# IF and ELSE in TRY CATCH?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code

```
root = new Root();
root.checkRootMethod2();
TextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4); 

if(root.checkRootMethod2()) {
    TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 01</b><br>"));
} else {
    TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 02</b><br>"));
}

try {
    if (root.RootAvailibility() && (root.checkRootMethod3())) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
            stdin.flush();
            stdin.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
        TextView.append(Html.fromHtml(
            "<b><font color=\"green\">TEXT 03</b></font>"));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    root.busybox();
    TextView.append(Html.fromHtml(
        "<br><b><font color=\"green\">TEXT 04</b></font>"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    TextView.append(Html.fromHtml(
        "<br><b><font color=\"red\">TEXT05</b></font>"));
}
```

I wish that if  `if (root.RootAvailibility() && (root.checkRootMethod3())) return true` Viewing a `TextView` that says something.If return false, another TextView that displays something else. As happens for `root.checkRootMethod2 ();` Same goes for `root.busybox ();` Do you have any idea on how I can do? Now visualize always `Text04`

Comment: Put code of `checkRootMethod2`? is it getter of  *boolean* variable?

Comment: Work on your `if() elseif() else` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    if (root.RootAvailibility() && (root.checkRootMethod3()))
    {
       try
       {
        /// your code ...
        } 
        catch(Exception e){ }

     TextView.append(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=\"green\">TEXT 03</b></font>"));
    }
  }catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
// Codes here runs always regardless of if clause.
```

the code (`try` block in your case) runs regardless of the `if` condition as the `try` block clears the scope of `if` block.
Either put `try` completely inside `if` block or surround both `if,else` statement by a single `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the need of multiple try/catch here :

```
try {
    if (root.RootAvailibility() && (root.checkRootMethod3()))
    {

    try
    {
```

You can add one more catch(Exception e) to the upper try/catch block and that will serve the same purpose.
Secondly there is no else part to this if `(root.RootAvailibility() && (root.checkRootMethod3()))`. So, if it is false the program will simply move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're always going to see Text04 because there's no conditional that excludes it. The try catch block it's in is at the top level.

It would help if you could provide a short, self-contained, compilable example of your code. There's clearly other potentially relevant code missing. For example, the try that goes with that last catch block. Also, it might help you to comment the beginning and end of your code blocks so that you can tell what's included in the if else statements.